# Wordpress onClick function not working in li tag, posted link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am updating a wordpress website and for some reason, this onClick function is no longer working. Here it is in the html:

```
    <div class="monthes">
        <!--<div class="location_title">Great Wall Hiking Locations</div>-->
        <div class="month_list">
            <ul class="month">
            <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
                if($i!=$cur_month)
                   echo "<li onclick=\"tabTurn(this, 'on', 'month_desc');\" class=\"off\">$month[$i]</li>";
                else
                   echo "<li onclick=\"tabTurn(this, 'on', 'month_desc');\" class=\"on\">$month[$i]</li>";
            }?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the function:

```
function tabTurn(presObj, classon, showdiv){
    var pObj = presObj.parentNode;
    var items =pObj.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var n = i + 1;
        var cntDiv = $('location_desc_' + n);
        //alert(cntDiv);
        if(items[i] == presObj){
            items[i].className=classon;
            cntDiv.className = showdiv;
        }
        else{
            items[i].className='off';
            cntDiv.className = 'undis';
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this would stop working? Is there a way I can get rid of this inline onClick and just do it with javascript and not php? The issue can be found at this link here: http://staging.chinahiking.cn/agenda/

As you can see, the onclick is actually working and turning the months on/off, but the tabBurn function isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can use a passive event listener:

```
$(document).on("click", "class-name", function(){tabTurn(this, 'on', 'month_desc');});
```

where as "class-name" you need to add a class name to your `<li>` element (or an id)

Comment: I'm trying to do this with just javascript though. I tried adding that line of code above my function and adding a class name, but still having same issue where it's not changing. I've aded a link to the site

Comment: I visit the website, if you put a breakpoint on the function it does execute it at every click, then I'm not really sure of what the function is doing, maybe that is the issue